# HTML/Javascript form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am doing a simple form using HTML/CSS and Javascript. The idea is that the form will ask the user to type his name, email, age and phone number. After that whenever the user clicks on the "Done" button, these headers will disappear. 
"Enter your name"
"Enter your age"
"Enter your email"
"Enter your phone"

When I wrote the javascript code, these headers didn't disappear. So what is the problem?

```
        function display(){
            var input1 = document.getElementById("userA").value;
            document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = input1;

            var input2 = document.getElementById("ageA").value;
            document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = input2;

            var input3 = document.getElementById("emailA").value;
            document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = input3;

            var input4 = document.getElementById("phoneA").value;
            document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = input4;
        }


    </script>


    <div>
        <h1>Personal Information</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">

        <img src="download.png">

        <form name='myform'>
            <div class="form-input">    
                <h2  id="username">Enter your name</h2>
                <input   id="userA" type="text" name="username" >

            </div>

            <div class="form-input">
                <h2   id="age">Enter your age</h2>
                <input  id="ageA" type="text" name="age">

            </div>

            <div class="form-input">
                <h2   id="email">Enter your email</h2>
                <input   id="emailA"  type="text" name="email">

            </div>

            <div class="form-input">
                <h2   id="phone">Enter your phone</h2>
                <input   id="phoneA" type="text" name="phone">

            </div>

            <input type="submit" id="done" onclick="display()" value="Done" name="done">


        </form>

        <h1 id= "time"></h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Which part of your JS code do you think is hiding the headers?

Comment: There's nothing in your Javascript that makes anything disappear.

Comment: Is this a question a copy paste from somewhere?

Comment: When you click on the submit button it submits the form to the server, so the whole page should reload.

Comment: Use `<input type="button">` to prevent it from submitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are submitting the form, that will reload the page, so all changes done by your javascript is lost.

Try changing the submit button to a normal button e.g.

change

```
<input type="submit" id="done" onclick="display()" value="Done" name="done">
```

to

```
<button type="button" onclick="display()" >Done</button>
```

Comment: There's still nothing to make the headers disappear.

Comment: @Barmar have you tried it? The display function replaces the innerHTML in the headers.

Comment: document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = input1; will replace the innerHtml of the H2 tag

Comment: I misunderstood what he meant by "disappear".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this - it is basically the same, except it doesn't submit the form (because of the return false)

```js
        function display(){
            var input1 = document.getElementById("userA").value;
            document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = input1;

            var input2 = document.getElementById("ageA").value;
            document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = input2;

            var input3 = document.getElementById("emailA").value;
            document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = input3;

            var input4 = document.getElementById("phoneA").value;
            document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = input4;
            return false;
        }
```

```html
    <div>
        <h1>Personal Information</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">

        <img src="download.png">

        <form name='myform'>
            <div class="form-input">    
                <h2  id="username">Enter your name</h2>
                <input   id="userA" type="text" name="username" >

            </div>

            <div class="form-input">
                <h2   id="age">Enter your age</h2>
                <input  id="ageA" type="text" name="age">

            </div>

            <div class="form-input">
                <h2   id="email">Enter your email</h2>
                <input   id="emailA"  type="text" name="email">

            </div>

            <div class="form-input">
                <h2   id="phone">Enter your phone</h2>
                <input   id="phoneA" type="text" name="phone">

            </div>

            <input type="submit" id="done" onclick="return display()" value="Done" name="done">


        </form>

        <h1 id= "time"></h1>
    </div>
```